# Как из родительского процесса вызвать функцию запущенного дочернего прочесса?

Tags: linux, c, процесс

Есть PID-ы fork-процессов. Нужно из родительского процесса каждому отправить команду на выполнение некой инструкции. Суть именно в том, чтобы метод отработал в процессе.
Думал сделать это через сигналы, типа `kill -SigNum pid`, но кастомные сигналы, насколько я знаю, не предусмотренны.

Какие есть ещё варианты?

Comment: Это можно сделать посредством IPC.

Comment: А что значит "команду" ? Просто факт что надо запускать - да, сигралом, возьмите какой нравиться. Для таких вещей предусмотрены USR1 и USR2. Если надо передать какие либо еще данные - то например через pipe (которые надо заранее открыть для каждого дочернего процесса перед выполнением fork())

Comment: В дополнение к предложенному Mike могу порекомендовать очереди сообщений. Их достоинством является простота передачи произвольных данных вместе с сообщением. В Linux очереди реализованы на двух стандартах: System-V и POSIX. Функционально они практически не различаются, так что, чем пользоваться - дело вкуса.